# Convert all Objects in Array to Array

Tags: php, api

I have some values that grab off an API and store them into an array `$data` for insertion into my tables. However, I seem to have objects within the array `$data`, which seems kind of messy. Is it possible to convert all the contents of array `$data` into array elements?

**PHP Code**

```
$data['title'] = $item->ItemAttributes->Title;
$data['brand'] = $item->ItemAttributes->Brand;
$data['color'] = $item->ItemAttributes->Color;
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
```

**Output**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [title] => stdClass Object
        (
            [0] => La Martina Polo Shirt Scotland Polo, Color: Black, Size: L
        )

    [brand] => stdClass Object
        (
            [0] => La Martina
        )

    [color] => stdClass Object
        (
            [0] => Black
        )

)
```

Comment: And what is `$data` ? Was it initialized as an array ? Can you recreate the problem on http://codepad.viper-7.com ?

Comment: `$data` is just an empty array.

Comment: As you might notices in [this example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2fVfch), what you have there is not an array.

Comment: Somehow it became an array. I did not initialize it as an array though, maybe thats why when I pushed an object into `$data` using `$data[] = $obj`, `$data` becomes an array

Comment: What type does the `$item` have ?

Comment: `$item` is just an array, which is initialized the first time I used `$item[] = $someobject;`

Comment: No, `$item` is not an array, because you are calling `$item->ItemAttributes->Title;`.

Comment: Basically, the issue should be cause by magic `__get()` methods in whatever the `ItemAttributes` class is. It is quite possible that this method returned a reference, instead of the value. This is why i was asking "what is `$item`?", so that i would take a look at Laravel's source and see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont get you properly but if you do something like this

```
$data['title'] =(string)$item->ItemAttributes->Title;
$data['brand'] =(string)$item->ItemAttributes->Brand;
$data['color'] = (string)$item->ItemAttributes->Color;
```

.. might lead you to something like below:-

```
{'title'=>'some title','brand'=>,'color'=>'something'}
```

But I am not sure if that is what you want

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = get_object_vars($object);
```

If the members are protected or private, do it from inside the class.

If you aren't going to define a specific class, use [reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflection.examples.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
array get_object_vars ( object $object )
```

for more : http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php